# Javascript count numbers of each kind in array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to count each type of flower in the array 'flowers' which is stored in an array in an external library. There are three flowers, "rose", "marigold", and "tulip". I have an html page with a button when clicked,  will tell me how many of each flower are in the stored array. However, my program will not give me the count when run. Code looks right to me, so I have absolutely no idea whats wrong with it.

```
document.getElementById('go').onclick = function () {

roseCount = 0;

marigoldCount = 0;

tulipCount = 0;

lengthArray = flowers.length;

for (f = 0; f < lengthArray; f++) {

    if (flowers[f] == 'rose') {

        roseCount ++;

    };

    if (flowers[f] == 'marigold') {

        marigoldCount ++;

    };

    if (flowers[f] == 'tulip') {

        tulipCount ++;

    };

    document.getElementById('tulip').value = tulipCount;

    document.getElementById('rose').value = roseCount;

    document.getElementById('marigold').value = marigoldCount;

  };

};
```

HTML

```
<body>

    <button id = 'go' class = ''>COMPUTE</button>
    <input id = 'number' name = '' value = '' class = ''>
    <input id = 'sum' name = '' value = '' class = ''>
    <input id = 'average' name = '' value = '' class = ''>
    <script src = 'http://gobongo.net/information/24065/script/javascript array 02 data.js'></script>
    <script src = 'js/javascript 11.js'></script>
</body>
```

Comment: It's not at all clear where `flowers` comes from.

Comment: @Pointy flowers is already created in an external library. Stored in it are the three flowers. I am supposed to just use flowers

Comment: How is anyone supposed to help when you don't show the structure of the array and provide sample of expected results? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Also have you checked the developer console for errors?

Comment: Are spaces allowed in urls?

Comment: @charlietfl I dont know what's in the array. Thats supposed to be the point of what I am doing. My program is supposed to tell me the count. I am supposed to just use 'flowers' as if its been already created by me

Comment: @Jonasw yeah the space is supposed to be there

Comment: `Thats supposed to be the point of what I am doing`, Really, your meant to write a program, that counts flowers from a data structure nobody knows what it looks like..  Good look with that one..

Comment: @Keith lol what the hell, you think I want to be doing this. this is an assignment.  
ARRAY OF FLOWERS - COUNT NUMBER OF EACH KIND

OBJECTIVE

Use a for() loop to process an array. 

Each value in the array is the name of a flower: 'rose', 'marigold' or 'tulip'.

Count how many times each flower is found.

Comment: @Keith Do not create flowers. Do not assign values to flowers. The array flowers is created in javascript array 03 data.js. Just use the array flowers.

Comment: @Keith i just quoted you my directions

Comment: @Astonishing  Are you saying you have never heard the term `test data`??..  It's a very useful feature of programming.  In fact @Naren Murali gave you a very good example of such a case in his answer.

Comment: @Keith no i haven't heard of that since i'm in an introductory programming class, you should have a general idea of that by the difficulty of what I am asking. And my answer has to be exactly what I am asking for since my program is put into an automatic grader , I cant be adding things to my code even if it's another way to do it because it will be wrong

Comment: @Astonishing   The code @Naren Murali posted for you works, you can actually test this from SO, by clicking the `run snippet` button.   Now if you get his code, and remove the line were he has put the test data in, and submit this code you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to attach an `onclick` handler to an element before the document has finished loading. Therefore replace your code with:

```js
// ignore this line, you already have a flowers array
var flowers = ['rose','rose','rose','marigold','marigold','marigold','tulip','tulip'];

// wait for the DOM to load
window.onload = function() {

    // attach your event handler now the DOM is ready!       
    document.getElementById('go').addEventListener('click', function () {

        var roseCount = 0;
        var marigoldCount = 0;
        var tulipCount = 0;

        // calculate number of items
        for (var i=0, l=flowers.length; i<l; i++) {
            if (flowers[i] === 'rose') roseCount++;
            if (flowers[i] === 'marigold') marigoldCount++;
            if (flowers[i] === 'tulip') tulipCount++;
        }

        // update your inputs outside of the loop!
        document.getElementById('tulip').value = tulipCount;
        document.getElementById('rose').value = roseCount;
        document.getElementById('marigold').value = marigoldCount;
    });
}
```

```html
<!-- clean up your HTML... just to satisfy my OCD :) -->
<body>
  <button id="go">COMPUTE</button>
  <input id="tulip" name="tulip" value="">
  <input id="rose" name="rose" value="">
  <input id="marigold" name="marigold" value="">
  <script src="http://gobongo.net/information/24065/script/javascript array 02 data.js"></script>
  <script src="js/javascript 11.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok the HTML and the JS provided do not make sense together, so I got the function working so that you can analyze and see what is wrong.

**Issues:**

1. Use `var` instead of defining a variable just like that, if not it will become a global variable.

   ```
   var roseCount = 0;
   var marigoldCount = 0;
   var tulipCount = 0;
   var flowers = ['rose', 'marigold', 'tulip'];
   var lengthArray = flowers.length;
   ```
2. The `flowers` array was not even defined. I have done this.

   ```
   var flowers = ['rose', 'marigold', 'tulip'];
   ```
3. When the button is pressed we need to calculate so I wrapped the logic in a function called `calculate()` and call it with the HTML

   ```
   <button id = 'go' class = '' onclick='calculate()'>COMPUTE</button>
   ```

   So when the button is clicked the function is called!
4. Using the JS you are searching for `tulip rose and marigold` but theses HTML elements are not found, hence I added them with the below lines.

   ```
   <input id = 'tulip' name = 'tulip' value = '' class = ''>
   <input id = 'rose' name = 'rose' value = '' class = ''>
   <input id = 'marigold' name = 'marigold' value = '' class = ''>
   ```

Refer the below snippet and let me know if your issue is resolved, Thanks!

Also in your external js file there are spaces in the name, please remove them.

```js
function calculate() {
  var roseCount = 0;

  var marigoldCount = 0;

  var tulipCount = 0;
  var flowers = ['rose', 'marigold', 'tulip'];
  var lengthArray = flowers.length;

  for (f = 0; f < lengthArray; f++) {

    if (flowers[f] == 'rose') {

      roseCount++;

    };

    if (flowers[f] == 'marigold') {

      marigoldCount++;

    };

    if (flowers[f] == 'tulip') {

      tulipCount++;

    };

    document.getElementById('tulip').value = tulipCount;

    document.getElementById('rose').value = roseCount;

    document.getElementById('marigold').value = marigoldCount;

  };
}
```

```html
<body>

  <button id='go' class='' onclick='calculate()'>COMPUTE</button>
  <input id='tulip' name='tulip' value='' class=''>
  <input id='rose' name='rose' value='' class=''>
  <input id='marigold' name='marigold' value='' class=''>
  <script src='http://gobongo.net/information/24065/script/javascript array 02 data.js'></script>
  <script src='js/javascript 11.js'></script>
</body>
```

Comment: @Astonishing  Can you spot the `test data`??..  Now the really clever bit, if his program works with the `test data`, what chances do you think it will work with the real data..?.  Welcome to the world of programming..

Comment: @Astonishing were you able to fix your issue? The problem must be in the another jsfile where the array exists...make sure the array is defined properly as shown in the above snippet, also please make sure to give a name without spaces...maybe the source js file just isn't included in the HTML file